# Is it safe to use prefabs as look up table?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Assigning a prefab with a MonoBehaviour attached to it:

`Class1` is contained in a prefab and its values are set in the inspector. Then this prefab gets assigned, also in the inspector, to an instance of `MainClass.prefab`.

```c#
public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Size size = new Size();
}

public class MainClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Prefab with Class1 assigned in the inspector
    public GameObject prefab = null;
}
```

Then using it at runtime, somewhere and sometime under conditions. For the ease of it, this is just in the `MainClass.Update()`:

```c#
// MainClass 
public void Update()
{

    // Error check? In examples?
    GameObject go     = prefab;
    Class1     class1 = go.GetComponent<Class1>();
    Size       size   = new Size(class1.size.width, class1.size.depth);

    // swap width and depth if wanted/needed
    ...

    if( size == pseudo_fit )
    {

        go = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab);

        ...

    }

}
```

Is this safe or can it give unexpected results?

Comment: What do you mean under "Is it safe"?

Comment: @Morion if the values are persistant or not. It seems when using `Size size = class.size` makes a reference to the prefab's script rather then assigning the values.

Comment: In the case of value type, it will create a copy, in the case of an object, it will be a reference. The same as usual c#.

Comment: @Morion Started to suspect this as it seemed to be predictable. At first I didn't knew you could access these values of a script in a prefab. But reading and writing are both possible.